# CardView Dynamic Height

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a custom form that uses `CardView` to store elements. I have elements like the `EditText` element, which allows multiple lines of text. I've been trying to get the `CardView` height to match the height of the `EditText` dynamically as lines are added or removed, but it keeps staying fixed. Here is the code:

```
package com.cpjd.roblu.activities;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.cpjd.roblu.R;


public class TeamViewer extends Activity {

// adapters
LinearLayout layout;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_viewer);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.team_viewer_cards);

    // Initialize a new CardView
    CardView card = new CardView(getApplicationContext());

    // Set the CardView layoutParams
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            400
    );
    card.setLayoutParams(params);

    // Set CardView corner radius
    card.setRadius(9);

    // Set cardView content padding
    card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

    // Set a background color for CardView
    card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    // Set the CardView maximum elevation
    card.setMaxCardElevation(200);

    // Set CardView elevation
    card.setCardElevation(50);

    LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());


    // Initialize a new TextView to put in CardView
    TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(getApplicationContext());
    et.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    et.setSingleLine(false);
    et.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
    et.setHint("Hint");
    et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    et.setEnabled(true);
    et.requestFocus();
    l1.addView(et);
    card.addView(l1);

    // Finally, add the CardView in root layout
    layout.addView(card);


}

}
```

Comment: Set both of your cardview and edittext's height as wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: Set layout parameter of `Cardview` properly

```
 CardView card = new CardView(getApplicationContext());

            // Set the CardView layoutParams
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            card.setLayoutParams(params);



 // Put the Editext in CardView
card.addView(et);

// Finally, add the CardView in root layout
layout.addView(card);
```

Comment: Which package layout params to use ?

Comment: @MDDanishAnsari use `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;`...